# How to make form-flip (likes card-flip effect) on a web technologies

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, ajax

http://www.dailyliquordeals.net/

How to make a card flip effect like this.

[image]

after sign up completed, it will flip to the other side with fliping transitional effect.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to use **Flip!** JQuery plugin:

- http://lab.smashup.it/flip/

It seems to be quite nice and easy to use. It is compatible with almost all browsers:
Firefox, Chrome/Chromium, Opera, Safari and even IE (6,7,8).

---

Another option is **Flippy** JQuery plugin:

- http://blog.guilhemmarty.com/flippy/

It is also good and rather flexible. However it uses `canvas` to make effects and is not compatible with IE 6-8. You should use extra `excanvas.js` script to make it work in IE.

Answer (score 1):

This site is use the jQuery Mobile transitions effect.

You can see them all here, including the flip:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-transitions.html

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-transitions.html

The jQuery Flip is nice, but actually is flip only the background and not everything on it.

You can see also the jQTouch:  http://www.jqtouch.com/